# How to use the result of lp() as a value

Tags: r, lpsolve

I am using the `lp()` function, but would like to use the optimal parameter as an input for following functions. Is there a way to get them?

Comment: See the documentation on the lp.object list returned by lp().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use missing() to test whether or not the argument b was supplied:

```
myFunc <- function(a,b){
    if(missing(b)) {
        a
    } else {
        a + b
    }
}

myFunc(3,1.5)
# [1] 4.5
myFunc(3)
# [1] 3
```